# How can I check if user is owner of entity when he updates row in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, security, entity-framework

I have problem... I wrote an website and now I must secure my page. So the problem is... when user edits a entity then I should check if he is an owner of this entity. Traditionaly(without entity framework) I do it by including a where clause in sql query. For example:

```
update posts set
 title = "Great Post"
where 
 post_id = 5 and
 owner_id = " + CurrentLogedinUser.Id + "
```

But I dont know how can I do it in entity framework.

Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF, you'll typically load the item out of the context, change it, and put it back in. So you can check the value like this:

```
var post = context.Posts.Single(p => p.PostId == 5);
if(post.OwnerId != CurrentLoggedInUser.Id) throw new Exception("Stop hacking!");
post.title = "Great Post";
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yeah... i think this is sufficient. But performance isnt great in this solution. Isnt there any faster method?

Comment: What do you mean performance isn't great in this solution? The only thing you're adding is the `if` check - and that's just checking an integer against another (I assume). That won't slow it down at all.

Comment: But you must get the row first and then send it. In standard update you send once. And condition is checking on the db server.

Comment: @robson: That's one of the downsides to using an ORM: by treating your persisted data like objects, you sacrifice some performance. However, I would argue that fail-fast behavior is desirable enough here to make it worth the sacrifice. I would rather have an exception be thrown when a user is attempting to modify something they don't own than to simply pretend that everything is honky-dory without actually changing anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If `owner_id` is a property on your `Post` entity, then can't you just check that *before* submitting the update (or even before allowing them to edit it)?

Comment: Yes I can check it before allowing them to edit but if someone prepare form manualy and send it to serwer then this method wont work.

Comment: But checking before submitting the update (my first suggestion) would still prevent that.